# Compatibility of ESX 4 and LTO 3 with LSI2032 Dell Power Edge

Tags: vmware-esx, tape, tapedrive

does anybody know something about the compatibility of an LTO 3 Tapedrive (PV HH LTO 3 400GB) attached to an LSI2032 SCSI-Controller? These devices are added to an Dell PowerEdge T610 Server which is listed in the certified Compatibility Guide.

I can`t find any information for this controller and this tapdevice. Or are they automaticly compatible because they are options for an compatible Server?

greetings Dennis

Comment: Can you tell us how you intend to use this tape drive, are you going to pass it through to a VM or do you want it working from the COS/SC?

Comment: ah ok, missed your comment sorry, in that case you simply need to enable VT-d functionality in your BIOS if your CPU has it and then follow the following guide to hardware passthrough setup; http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/02/24/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-enable-vt-d-and-perform-direct-device-assignment/

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase a TBU set with an HBA with a Dell server, you should get a compatible HBA.
LSI is pretty much the standard SCSI HBA Dell ships, so as long as the TBU is ok, you should be fine.

If still in doubt, try to call the suport line and ask them